# css opacity on hover of div

Tags: css, hover

I am new to CSS. I just want a div over another div on hover and its transparency should increase. I have done some thing like that

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<div id="picture"><img src="bill.jpg" alt="Bill Gates"></div>
<h1>A floating image</h1>
<p id="bill"></p>
<div id="mem">sfasdf</div>
</div>
<div id="column1">
<p>Haec disserens qua de re agatur et in quo causa consistat non
videt...</p>
</div>
<div id="column2">
<p>causas naturales et antecedentes, idciro etiam nostrarum
voluntatum...</p>
</div>
<div id="column3">
<p>nam nihil esset in nostra potestate si res ita se haberet...</p>
</div>
<div id="slide">
<ul>
    <li id="ims"><img src="test.jpg" height="200" width="200" /></li>
    <li id="sp"></li>
    <li id="ims"><img src="test.jpg" height="200" width="200" /></li>
    <li id="sp"></li>
    <li id="ims"><img src="test.jpg" height="200" width="200" /></li>
    <li id="sp"></li>
    <li id="ims"><img src="test.jpg" height="200" width="200" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="left">l</div>
<div id="right">R</div>
```

and css file is

```
body {
    background-color: #FFCC66;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#picture {
    height: 200px;
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
}

#column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

#column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

#bill {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#mem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 150px;
}

#slide {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 220px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 500px;
    left: 400px;
    background-color: #333399;
    z-index: 1;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #FF33CC;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: .5;
}

#left :hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #CCCC00;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 10);
    -moz-opacity: 10;
    -khtml-opacity: 10;
    opacity: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to increase transparency of div with id left on hover

Comment: I can see you are not really good at english, but it would definitely help if you could run a spell check. I am no grammar nazi, but as a reader, it becomes easy to skim through correct text and chances are that you will be taken more seriously! <br>Just an advice in good sense

Answer (score 12):

I'm afraid hovering of `div` elements is not supported in our favourite browser (IE6), but if you're willing to drop support, the following code should work:

```
#left {
    opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
}

#left:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}
```

Comment: You'll need to look at something like how the suckerfish dropdowns work in IE6 by applying a class on-hover. IE6 only likes :hover on anchor elements.

Comment: Don't forget -webkit-opacity and -khtml-opacity.

Comment: +1 @Marcel for attention to detail. I was trying to keep it short and sweet though. Also @dylanfm I did touch on IE6's :hover problem, maybe a simpler solution would be to use As instead of DIVs. It depends on what the content of the DIV will be.

Comment: and -ms-filter:alpha(opacity=100); for IE8 that is kept css right.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't looked closely at your code but one thing:

This

```
   #left :hover{
```

is most likely not what you want. You want

```
   #left:hover{
```

it means, the element with the ID `left` when the mouse hovers over it.
Maybe that already helps solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want transparency on old browsers use a transparent .png with a light grey or whatever and apply it as a div on top of your other div. Make sure you use position:fixed so it floats together with the scroll, else as you scroll you end up underneath it.