# How to change the opacity of image on hover using css

Tags: jquery, image, css, hover

I'm trying to figure out how to set all images to be **50% opacity initially**, and then change to **100% opacity on hover**.

I tried setting this rule in the `.css` file but it gives a parse error:

```
img {
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40); 
}
img:hover {
  opacity:1.0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244566/css-opacity-on-hover-of-div?rq=1) will possibly help

Comment: Is there more code we're not seeing that could be overriding your opacity settings?

Comment: Could the issue be that you are using `:hover` on an `<img>` tag? Using hover on elements other than an `<a>` tag can cause issues in some versions of ie.

Comment: What is the parse error?

Comment: hmm weird, it works fine now. I was using webstorm. It just gives a warning

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your code is good- verified in this Fiddle with a friendly fish: http://jsfiddle.net/Qrufy/

```css
    img {
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    }
    
    img:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
```

```html
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Colossoma_macropomum_01.jpg/800px-Colossoma_macropomum_01.jpg" />
```

The `opacity` property works in all modern browsers, and the `filter:alpha` covers <= IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a better and smooth output

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```