# How to toggle a div's visibility on hover?

Tags: html, css

I What to create a div that behaves similar to audio controls. Audio controls such that 
 the controls are not visible, but on hovering the cursor where the elements are hidden makes them visible. The following code tries to achieve this but it doesn't work.

```css
.toggle{
  height:200px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.toggle:hover{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="toggle">I want to be seen on hover!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244566/css-opacity-on-hover-of-div and many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use opacity for this.

```css
.toggle{
  height:200px;
  opacity:0;
}

.toggle:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">I want to be seen on hover!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why toggling the visibility doesn't work?

Comment: because when it is hidden, there is no hover effect. because it's hidden.

Answer (score 1):

another option you have is to wrap the content you might want to hide into another div, which has the `:hover` hover pseudo class

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="toggle">
        <div>I want to be seen on hover!</div>  
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.toggle div {
  height:200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle:hover div {
  visibility:visible;
}
```